# Read test results from /dev/ttyUSB0 in gradle

Tags: serial-port, gradle

I use gradle to upload tests on Arduino (a microcontoller). I can get the test output (on my ubuntu) through /dev/ttyUSB0.

I am looking now for the easiest way to get the test output in gradle. I have made some experiments with *cat* (ant.exec):

```
def checkTestResults = {
    ant.exec(
        outputproperty:"cmdOut",
        errorproperty: "cmdErr",
        resultproperty: "cmdExit",
        failonerror:"true",
        dir: './MyArduinoTests',
        searchpath:"true",
        executable: 'cat') {    
            arg(value:"/dev/ttyUSB0")
        }
        println ant.cmdOut  
}
```

It does not work very well. I do not get the complete output of the serial port. Sometimes, I do not get any output.

How to accomplish this task without writing a separate program that reads the port?

Comment: My tests show that both:
    sudo cat /dev/ttyS0     (connected an input device directly to serial port)
    sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0   (connected the same input device to USB port over serial-to-USB hardware adapter)  work seamlessly from console which leads to conclusion that your problem might be a gradle issue. Writing a separate simple serial program reader isn't at all that much of a job, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to write a separate program that reads the port. My colleague wrote simply 8 line of  python code.